# how to limit row content in multiple JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

> Updated to what Strawberry recommended
>
> I am working on a DB that handles game cards, and creating a view.

```
select 
kort_info.id, 
kk_b.Antall as 'kk_b.Antall',  
kk_b.Kjop_id as 'kk_b.Kjop_id', 
kk_c.Antall as 'kk_c.Antall',
kk_c.Kjop_id as 'kk_c.Kjop_id'
from kort_info
left join kort_kjopt kk_b on kort_info.id = kk_b.kort_id and kk_b.kort_type like 'b' 
left join kort_kjopt kk_c on kort_info.id = kk_c.kort_id and kk_c.kort_type like 'c'
```

```
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
|                                  Result                                      |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| id             |  kk_b.Antall |  kk_b.Kjop_id |  kk_c.Antall |  kk_c.Kjop_id |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| 5879           | 1            | 23            | 2            | 18            |
| 5902           | 3            | 23            | 4            | 23            |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
|                                Desired result                                |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| id             |  kk_b.Antall |  kk_b.Kjop_id |  kk_c.Antall |  kk_c.Kjop_id |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| 5879           |              |               | 2            | 18            |
| 5879           | 1            | 23            |              |               |
| 5902           | 3            | 23            | 4            | 23            |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
```

> My problem is how to JOIN multiple times to the same table. My problem
>   is how JOIN handles Kort_kjopt.kjop_id. This is a value I cannot
>   controle against Kort_info.
>
> I have got a tabel with info about cards.   Kort_info.ID is used to
>   identify cards.

```
+--------------+
| Kort_info.ID |
+--------------+
|         5879 |
|         5902 |
+--------------+
```

> Kort_kjopt is the tabel about bought cards 
>   Kort_kjopt.Kort_id is connected to kort_info.ID 
>   Kort_kjopt.kort_type decides  which JOIN its connected to 
>   Kort_kjopt.kjop_id is where the problem appears.

```
+----------+------------+----------+---------+
|                    Kort_kjopt              |
+----------+------------+----------+---------+
|  kort_id |  kort_type |  Kjop_id |  Antall |
+----------+------------+----------+---------+
|     5879 | B          |       23 |       1 |
|     5879 | C          |       18 |       2 |
|     5902 | B          |       23 |       3 |
|     5902 | C          |       23 |       4 |
+----------+------------+----------+---------+
```

> kjop_id excist only in Kort_kjopt and cannot be conected from
>   Kort_info
>
> I ned to limit which values Kort_kjopt.kjop_id can have in the same
>   row. How can I get the same value kk_b.Kjop_id and
>   kk_c.Kjop_id in a row
>
> This is not about inheritance

card_id 5879 is divided into two different rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that it was better to connect 3 kort_kjopt to one kort_kjopt which worked as a link between them.

```
SELECT 
kort_kjopt.kort_id,
kort_kjopt.Kjop_id,
kk_a.Antall as 'kk_a.Antall',  
kk_a.Kjop_id as 'kk_a.Kjop_id', 
kk_b.Antall as 'kk_b.Antall',  
kk_b.Kjop_id as 'kk_b.Kjop_id', 
kk_c.Antall as 'kk_c.Antall',
kk_c.Kjop_id as 'kk_c.Kjop_id'
FROM 
poketech.kort_kjopt
left join kort_kjopt kk_a on kk_a.kort_id = kort_kjopt.kort_id and kk_a.Kjop_id = kort_kjopt.Kjop_id and kk_a.kort_type = 'A'
left join kort_kjopt kk_b on kk_b.kort_id = kort_kjopt.kort_id and kk_b.Kjop_id = kort_kjopt.Kjop_id and kk_b.kort_type = 'B'
left join kort_kjopt kk_c on kk_c.kort_id = kort_kjopt.kort_id and kk_c.Kjop_id = kort_kjopt.Kjop_id and kk_c.kort_type = 'C'
where kort_kjopt.kort_id in (5879,5902)
group by kort_kjopt.Kjop_id, kort_kjopt.kort_id
```